# Pokemon go not able to login with gmail

Tags: pokemon-go

So I was able to play fine a week ago. But now I get stuck on a loading screen. If I use a gmail account for the 1st time it works fine but only the 1st time. And the trainer club always works. I have removed and readded my Google account force stopped the game cleared cache and data. Reinstalled the game. Nothing is working. I have also tried to root my device still doesn't change a thing. I can give files or pics when needed

Answer (score 0):

The servers are currently down right now for google authentication and pokemon trainer club for the US. In europe, both work. Just wait until the servers go back online :D

Comment: But 2 days ago my friend was playing with his Google account and I still couldn't play even today I'm still down. I have also now factory reset